# Merge function will only work for ordered list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this 2 lists as input:

```
list1 = [['A', 14, 'I', 10, 20], ['B', 15, 'S', 30, 40], ['C', 16, 'F', 50, 60]]
list2 = [['A', 14, 'Y', 0, 200], ['B', 15, 'M', 0, 400], ['C', 17, 'G', 0, 600]]
```

and my desired output will be this:

```
finalList = [['A', 14, 'Y', 10, 200], ['B', 15, 'M', 30, 400], ['C', 16, 'F', 50, 60],['C', 17, 'G', 0, 600]]
```

Using this function:

```
def custom_merge(list1, list2):
    finalList = []
    for sub1, sub2 in zip(list1, list2):
        if sub1[1]==sub2[1]:
            out = sub1.copy()
            out[2] = sub2[2]
            out[4] = sub2[4]
            finalList.append(out)
        else:
            finalList.append(sub1)
            finalList.append(sub2)
    return finalList
```

I will get indeed my desired output, but what if I switch positions (list2[1] and list2[2]) and my list2:

```
list2 = [['A', 14, 'Y', 0, 200], ['C', 17, 'G', 0, 600], ['B', 15, 'M', 0, 400]]
```

Then the output will be this:

```
[['A', 14, 'Y', 10, 200], ['B', 15, 'S', 30, 40], ['C', 17, 'G', 0, 600], ['C', 16, 'F', 50, 60], ['B', 15, 'M', 0, 400]]
```

(notice the extra ['B', 15, 'M', 0, 400])

What I have to modify in my function in order to get my first desired output if my lists have a different order in my list of lists!? I use python 3. Thank you!

LATER EDIT:

Merge rules:
When `list1[listindex][1] == list2[listindex][1]` (ex: when `14==14`), replace in `list1` -> `list2[2]` and `list2[4]` (ex: 'Y' and 200) and if not just add the unmatched list from `list2` to `list1` as it is (like in my desired output) and also keep the ones that are in list1 that aren't matched(ex: `['C', 16, 'F', 50, 60]`)

To be noted that list1 and list2 can have different len (list1 can have more lists than list2 or vice versa)

EDIT.2
I found this:

```
def combine(list1,list2):
    combined_list = list1 + list2
    final_dict = {tuple(i[:2]):tuple(i[2:]) for i in combined_list}
    merged_list = [list(k) + list (final_dict[k]) for k in final_dict]
    return merged_list
```

^^ That could work, still testing!

Comment: Not sure what is the merge logic here.

Comment: Added the merge rules in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the lists by the first element in the sublists before merging them.

```
def custom_merge(list1, list2):
    finalList = []
    for sub1, sub2 in zip(sorted(list1), sorted(list2)):
        if sub1[1]==sub2[1]:
            out = sub1.copy()
            out[2] = sub2[2]
            out[4] = sub2[4]
            finalList.append(out)
        else:
            finalList.append(sub1)
            finalList.append(sub2)
    return finalList
```

tests:

```
list1 = [['A', 14, 'I', 10, 20], ['B', 15, 'S', 30, 40], ['C', 16, 'F', 50, 60]]
list2 = [['A', 14, 'Y', 0, 200], ['C', 17, 'G', 0, 600], ['B', 15, 'M', 0, 400]]
custom_merge(list1, list2)
# returns:
[['A', 14, 'Y', 10, 200],
 ['B', 15, 'M', 30, 400],
 ['C', 16, 'F', 50, 60],
 ['C', 17, 'G', 0, 600]]
```

Comment: Hmm, if I add for example to list2 a extra list: ['S', 20, 'Y', 0, 200], I won't actually see it in the output

Comment: @TatuBogdan: zip will always truncate to the shorted iterable.  So if you provide it with a list of 3 elements and a list of 10 elements, you will on get a the first 3 elements from the longer list.

Comment: I see, but my list1 and list2 won't have the same len.